# Freeze activity after Dialog prompt on onActivityResult function

Tags: android

I want my application to continue accepting image from the gallery if I chose Upload Image from the dialog box, but the problem is that the function will continue to finish (the log for count is printed even if I didn't pressed any button, and the conditional statement will set cont = false). The decision variable is a global string variable.

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
       boolean cont = true;
        while (cont == true) {
            if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
               functionHere();
            }
            if (requestCode == OPEN_DOCUMENT_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (data != null) {
                    // this is the image selected by the user
                    try {
                         functionHere();
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        Log.i("Error", ex.toString());

                    }
                }
            }

            continuePrompt();

            if(decision == "Upload"){
                requestCode = OPEN_DOCUMENT_CODE;
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, OPEN_DOCUMENT_CODE);
            }
            else if(decision == "Take Picture"){
                //code here
            }
            else if(decision == "End"){
                cont = false;
            }
            else{
                cont = false;
            }
            Log.d("Count", Integer.toString(count));
        }
        if (cont == false) {
            //output result
        }
    }
```

Here is my code for my dialog which I get from another question here in stackoverflow

```
    public void continuePrompt() {
        // setup the alert builder
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Platelet detection");
        builder.setMessage("Are all microscopic slide image uploaded?");

        // add the buttons
        builder.setPositiveButton("Upload Image", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                decision = "Upload";
            }
        });
        builder.setNeutralButton("Take Picture", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                decision =  "Take Picture";
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("End", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                decision = "End";
            }
        });
        // create and show the alert dialog
        builder.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you still have below line in your code

```
while (cont == true)
```

even when you show your dialog this loop is iterating over and over again. you should fix your logic, there shouldn't be any `while` loop, everything is already in UI thread and with above line you are hanging it showing dialogs one after another. you should show your prompt once and instead of setting global `decision` variable just place your code response for action in listener

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        functionHere();
        continuePrompt();
    }
    else if (requestCode == OPEN_DOCUMENT_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (data != null) {
            // this is the image selected by the user
            try {
                 functionHere();
                 continuePrompt();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.i("Error", ex.toString());

            }
        }
    }
    else{
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}

private void continueFlow(){
    if("Upload".equals(decision)){
        requestCode = OPEN_DOCUMENT_CODE;
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, OPEN_DOCUMENT_CODE);
    }
    else if("Take Picture".equals(decision)){
        //code here
    }
}
```

just call `continueFlow();` after every `decision` change (in every listener). or move code form `if("Upload".equals(decision)){` straight to `setPositiveButton` and so on

btw. `decision == "Upload"` won't ever be `true` as `==` operator is comparing same objects. `decision` is already declared variable and `"Upload"` `String` is freshly created in `if` statement, its brand new variable. for comparing content of `String`s (same text) use `stringOne.equals(stringTwo);`

Comment: Hi! This work perfectly (I made some changes to be able to display the result). Thank you so much for the effort and in also regarding string comparison. I didn't know that there is an Java equivalent to String.Equals of C#.